# Multi query with group by , join them in different columns

Tags: mysql, query

One table has different columns for each column I want to do a group by function. I get unique values for each column in the table.

Origin Table data:

```
+----+--------------+--------------+
| id | customername | amazonnumber |
+----+--------------+--------------+
|  1 | Mark         |         1122 |
|  2 | Pieter       |         1122 |
|  3 | Jean         |         1122 |
|  4 | Jean         |         1122 |
|  5 | Janis        |         1123 |
|  6 | Janis        |         1123 |
+----+--------------+--------------+
```

At this moment i do this:

```
SELECT customername FROM tablegroup  group by customername; 
SELECT amazonnumber FROM tablegroup  group by amazonnumber;
```

This is great i get for each column the unique value.

I want to combine them so i get all the data vertical in columns.
I have tried this but, this give not the right results:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT customername FROM tablegroup  group by customername) b
 CROSS JOIN
(SELECT amazonnumber FROM tablegroup  group by amazonnumber) c;
```

This is the wrong result:

```
+---------------+--------------+
| customername  | amazonnumber |
+---------------+--------------+
| Mark          |        11222 |
| Pieter        |        11222 |
| Jean          |        11222 |
| Janis         |        11222 |
+---------------+--------------+
```

End Result:

```
+---------------+--------------+
| customername  | amazonnumber |
+---------------+--------------+
| Mark          |        11222 |
| Pieter        |        11223 |
| Jean          |              |
| Janis         |              |
+---------------+--------------+
```

Comment: Show `create table tablegroup`. Show some sample data as its unclear as to who the end result is a grouping. Avoid using 'wanna' as its not a word and just makes you sound like an infant.

Comment: @danblack thx, i have add sample data

Answer (score 1):

For MySQL 8+:

```
WITH RECURSIVE
cte1 AS ( SELECT customername, ROW_NUMBER() OVER () rn
          FROM tablegroup
          GROUP BY customername 
        ),
cte2 AS ( SELECT amazonnumber, ROW_NUMBER() OVER () rn 
          FROM tablegroup
          GROUP BY amazonnumber 
        ),
cte3 AS ( SELECT 1 num
          UNION ALL
          SELECT num+1 
          FROM cte3
          WHERE num < ( SELECT GREATEST(cnt1, cnt2)
                        FROM ( SELECT COUNT(*) cnt1
                               FROM cte1
                             ),
                             ( SELECT COUNT(*) cnt2
                               FROM cte2
                             )
                      )
        )
SELECT cte1.customername, cte2.amazonnumber
FROM cte3
LEFT JOIN cte1 ON cte3.num = cte1.rn
LEFT JOIN cte2 ON cte3.num = cte2.rn
```

Answer (score 1):

Another MySQL 8+ option:

```
WITH
  ranked AS
  (
    SELECT
      customername,
      amazonnumber,
      DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY customername ASC) AS cust_rn,
      DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY amazonnumber ASC) AS amaz_rn
    FROM
      tablegroup
  ),
  allrankings AS
  (
    SELECT DISTINCT
      x.rn
    FROM
      ranked,
      LATERAL
      (
        SELECT ranked.cust_rn AS rn
        UNION ALL
        SELECT ranked.amaz_rn
      ) AS x
  )
SELECT
  c.customername,
  a.amazonnumber
FROM
  allrankings AS r
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT customername, cust_rn FROM ranked) AS c ON r.rn = c.cust_rn
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT amazonnumber, amaz_rn FROM ranked) AS a ON r.rn = a.amaz_rn
;
```

The `ranked` CTE generates unique rankings for `customername` and for `amazonnumber`. It transforms your data sample like this:

```
+--------------+--------------+---------+---------+
| customername | amazonnumber | cust_rn | amaz_rn |
+--------------+--------------+---------+---------+
| Mark         |         1122 |       3 |       1 |
| Pieter       |         1122 |       4 |       1 |
| Jean         |         1122 |       2 |       1 |
| Jean         |         1122 |       2 |       1 |
| Janis        |         1123 |       1 |       2 |
| Janis        |         1123 |       1 |       2 |
+--------------+--------------+---------+---------+
```

The `allrankings` CTE derives all the unique rankings from both ranking columns of `ranked`:

```
+----+
| rn |
+----+
|  1 |
|  2 |
|  3 |
|  4 |
+----+
```

Then all the unique combinations of `(customername, cust_rn)`:

```
+--------------+---------+
| customername | cust_rn |
+--------------+---------+
| Janis        |       1 |
| Jean         |       2 |
| Mark         |       3 |
| Pieter       |       4 |
+--------------+---------+
```

and all the unique combinations of `(amazonnumber, amaz_rn)`:

```
+--------------+---------+
| amazonnumber | amaz_rn |
+--------------+---------+
|         1122 |       1 |
|         1123 |       2 |
+--------------+---------+
```

are outer-joined against the `allrankings` set to produce the following output:

```
+--------------+--------------+
| customername | amazonnumber |
+--------------+--------------+
| Janis        |         1122 |
| Jean         |         1123 |
| Mark         |              |
| Pieter       |              |
+--------------+--------------+
```

Admittedly, it slightly differs from your expected output because of the order of values in `customername`. I believe this to be a minor issue because there is no meaningful relationship between `customername` and `amazonnumber` in either this or your output anyway.

This solution can be tested using [this live demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ae7578db2016faebda4c9a6f7c483ceb) at [image: dbfiddle logo]db<>fiddle.uk.

Other useful links:

- [Lateral Derived Tables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/lateral-derived-tables.html)
- [Window Function Descriptions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html)

  - [`DENSE_RANK`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_dense-rank)